# Can I build a plugin based application using VueJs and Quasar?

Tags: vue.js, plugins, components, webapi, quasar

I want to build a web application with Vuejs and Quasar (I'm using SFC with build step).
This web application should be plugin based, where plugins should be loaded from a REST webapi and injected in the webpage.
I can do this by making the webapi return html and javascript code, but it seems that in this way I'm limited to use standard html controls, without leveraging the power of Quasar layout and controls.
In a nutshell, is there a way to do something similar to the following, where the call to the webapi should return a Vuejs component that uses Quasar?

```
<script setup>
import ButtonCounter from 'https://mywebapi/Plugin/GetComponent/100'
...
</script>

<template>
    <ButtonCounter></ButtonCounter>
    ...
</template>
```

I'm new to Vuejs and Quasar so I'm asking if something similar is possibile.

Comment: It is indeed possible, but why you want to do that ? It has a door for security issues.

Comment: I would have liked to make it easily extensible, but that was also a curiosity of mine.